# Clean math solution to iterate circular carousel

Tags: javascript, for-loop, carousel

I am struggling to come up with a clean solution for this:

- The carousel has 7 items, so 0 - 6.
- Index 3 is the middle one
- If for example the 2nd item (index 1) is clicked each item needs to move 2 places to the right. If the last item is clicked (index 6) it would need to move 3 places to the left.

```
function centerCarouselOn(index, callback) {
  var items = $('li', carousel);
  var middleIdx = Math.floor(items.length / 2);
  var direction = null;
  var iterCount = 0;

  if(index === middleIdx) return;

  if(index > middleIdx) {
    direction = 'left';
    iterCount = (index - middleIdx);
  }
  else {
    direction = 'right';
    iterCount = (middleIdx - index);
  }

  $('li', carousel).each(function(k, v) {
    var li = $(v);

    // Here I need to iterate n places to the left or right
    // e.g:
    // direction = left, iterCount = 3
    // Then each li by index would need this sequence:
    // 0: 6, 5, 4
    // 1: 0, 6, 5
    // 2: 1, 0, 6
    // 3: 2, 1, 0
    // 4: 3, 2, 1
    // 5: 4, 3, 1
    // 6: 5, 4, 3 (this one moves to center - index 3)
  });

}
```

Comment: You can check my approach here: http://github.com/mgechev/jqcarousel. Here is a demo: http://carousel.mgechev.com/

Comment: "Then each li by index would need this sequence". Why a sequence?

Comment: Because the carousel is of people of different shapes and sizes, there is a default animation path, but then each person can also override this path (merges into default path) to make it look better. So in order to look good each person has to move through these paths.
+ thanks @MinkoGechev, I am having trouble extracting what I need for my simpler, less generic solution but nonetheless that is some nice looking code!

Comment: So basically, in your example, someone clicked on person 6, which happens to be 3 positions to the right compared to the front li of the carousel, and you want to move everyone 3 times 1 place to the left, right?

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does not include any code for animation, and it also assumes that the `carousel` element is the parent `<ul>` of the `<li>`s.

It *should* be unnecessary to change the indicies of each `<li>` for every 'move'.  All you really need to do is move the last element to the first position, or the first element to the last position (depending on direction you are moving).  I also added a `timeout` of 1 second so you should be able to see it stepping through.

```
function centerCarouselOn(index, callback) {
  var items = $('li', carousel);
  var middleIdx = Math.floor(items.length / 2);
  var direction = null;
  var iterCount = 0;

  if(index === middleIdx) return;

  // if iterCount is positive, we are going right; else, we are going left
  iterCount = middleIdx - index;

  // this funciton gets called recursively until all moves are complete
  function moveCarousel() {
    if (iterCount===0) return;

    if (iterCount > 0) {
      // take the last element, prepend it to the carousel
      $('li', carousel).last().prependTo(carousel);
      iterCount--;
    } else if (iterCount < 0) {
      // take the first element, append it to the carousel
      $('li', carousel).first().appendTo(carousel);
      iterCount++;
    }

    // execute callback to apply css changes at each step
    callback();

    // set a delay, then repeat.
    window.setTimeout(moveCarousel, 1000);
  }

  // start moving the carousel
  moveCarousel(iterCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the time you took to answer this. Unfortunately I do need to move incrementally as there is a specific set of css at each stage that each element must pass through!

Comment: edited to add call to the callback method your passing into the `centerCarouselOn`.  i assume this is where you are applying the incremental css changes?  i believe this should work.

Comment: I didn't use your code but it turns out the animation looks much better if it doesn't animate in between but goes all the way to where it is supposed to go so i'll choose it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your attention, this is how I did it in the end:

```
function centerCarouselOn(index, callback) {
  var items = $('li', carousel);
  var numItems = carousel.children().length;
  var middleIdx = Math.floor(items.length / 2);
  var direction = null;
  var iterCount = 0;

  if(index === middleIdx) return;

  if(index > middleIdx) {
    direction = 'left';
    iterCount = (index - middleIdx);
  }
  else {
    direction = 'right';
    iterCount = (middleIdx - index);
  }

  $('li', carousel).each(function(k, v) {
    var li = $(v);

    // Here I need to iterate n places to the left or right
    // e.g:
    // direction = left, iterCount = 3
    // Then each li by index would need this sequence:
    // 0: 6, 5, 4
    // 1: 0, 6, 5
    // 2: 1, 0, 6
    // 3: 2, 1, 0
    // 4: 3, 2, 1
    // 5: 4, 3, 1
    // 6: 5, 4, 3 (this one moves to center - index 3)

    if(direction === 'right') {
      for(var i = k; i < (k + iterCount); i++) {
        var thisIter = i;
        var nextIter = (++thisIter >= numItems) ? (thisIter - numItems) : thisIter;

        console.log(k + ': ' + nextIter);

      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = k; i > (k - iterCount); i--) {
        var thisIter = i;
        var nextIter = (--thisIter < 0) ? (numItems + thisIter) : thisIter;

        console.log(k + ': ' + nextIter);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Turns out animation looks crap like this so instead I am just calculating the final position (and it is more efficient as a bonus):

```
$('li', carousel).each(function(k, v) {
  var li = $(v);

  var nextIdx = 0;

  if(direction === 'right') {
    nextIter = ((k + iterCount) > (numItems - 1)) ? ((k + iterCount) - numItems) : (k + iterCount);
  }
  else {
    nextIter = (k - iterCount) >= 0 ? (k - iterCount) : numItems - (iterCount - k);
  }

  _animateTo(li, nextIter, direction);
});
```